# .NET MVC Dynamically add/remove items without using javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

I am on a C# .NET MVC project, and have a form that can dynamically add/remove n number of complex objects in a list. This complex object, for example represents a Person. This person has FirstName and Address properties.

When the user loads the page, all the People in the system are displayed in a list. When the user presses the 'add' button, two new text boxes show up for the Person's FirstName and Address properties. When the user presses the submit button, it will make a POST request to the server.

I know that you can write regular html in the View, and can use Javascript to add the new DOM elements for the FirstName and Address properties.

And with regards to when the user submits, I can use javascript to scrape all the data in the screen, and send a POST request to the server. Theoretically, another method is instead of using javascript, just make the button submit the form to the POST action of the controller; if I give my DOM elements the proper name attribute, the Action should recognize the data.

However, is there a MVC way of doing this? Maybe, with the help of Razor Helpers?

Comment: you can't do it without JavaScript. the best you can do is to get rendered HTML (using Razor) from Server and replace where needed.

Comment: "instead of using javascript, just make the button submit the form to the POST action of the controller" Yes. That's how the web worked before people though of Ajax. Default generated views in ASP.Net work exactly this way, _but_ of course they won't dynamically add new form fields. You need javascript for that

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking here; is it how to remove and add lists to your table or is it how to make a post?

I'll try to answer both:

### 1: Post without javascript:

Your assumption that you can post by naming the properties is correct! However, the page will have to reload if you want the new person in your table. Reading your description, I don't think this is really what you are looking for.

### 2: Add a row without javascript:

This cannot be done. You need javascript for this or a javascript framework which uses data-binding (there are a lot)

I would strongly advise you to make a decision on if a page reload is a deal-breaker or not for your solution. If it is, try to solve your issue with jQuery or better yet: investigate in javascript frameworks which use data-binding (knockoutjs, angular, react, etc...). There is a learning curve to these frameworks but they make your developer life so much easier and increase the maintainability of your code.